# How to write between XML tag in qt using QDomElement?

Tags: xml, qt, tags

I am trying to create an XML with QDomElement, like;

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ECU>


<DATE DATE="mer. mai 2 2012"/>
 <FILE/>
 <CONFIGURATION>
  <SESSION />
  <TYPE TYPE="Défaut"/>
 </CONFIGURATION>
 <DETAILS>
  <SELECTED-REQUESTS>
   <TEST/>
   <TIMEOUT/>
   <SENT-TRAM />
   <RECEIVED-TRAM/>
   <POS-RESPONSE/>
   <STATUS STATUS/>
  </SELECTED-REQUESTS>
  <SELECTED-REQUESTS>
   <TEST/>
   <TIMEOUT />
   <SENT-TRAM />
   <RECEIVED-TRAM />
   <POS-RESPONSE />
   <STATUS />
  </SELECTED-REQUESTS>
 </DETAILS>
</ECU>
```

The thing I could not do is that, I could not insert a text btw the tags, I can just add as an attribute;

```
<POS-RESPONSE POS-RESPONSE="77"/>
```

How can I add the value btw the tags with using QDomElement ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the documentation for [`QDomNode::appendChild()`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qdomnode.html#appendChild) which is inherited by `QDomElement`. You probably want to create a new node of type `QDomNode::TextNode`, then append that as the child of the POS-RESPONSE tag node.